# how to read u-boot env from x-loader

Tags: linux, u-boot

In my X-loader, I have to read u-boot env and few other data which I will be saving into u-boot env partition. Based on the data saved in u-boot env partision I have to perform some task.

Could anybody help me how can I read these env from x-loader?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot env variables are stored in Flash memory, you have to know in which adress.

Then you will be able to read these variables.